# Can't connect from an amazon ec2 instance to a mysql server on an external host

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, firewall

I have a mysql server hosted on a dedicated server on hostgator. I have an amzon ec2 instance with mysql installed on it. I connected to the ec2 instance through SSH using putty. I am trying to connect the mysql server on my external host from the ec2 instance

## mysql -h XXX.XXX.XX.XXX -u XXXX -p

i get a ERROR 2003 (HY000) ...

I have checked all possible issue and the only thing tha i can think of is the amazon firewall.

If I reverse the process and try to connect to the ec2 mysql db from my external serverthrough SSh. it works.

I have also connected to the same external server from another external server.

Please does anyone have a solution why i can't connect to an external db from an amazon ec2 instance

Comment: how is the external MySQL server firewalled? Can it accept connections on port 3306 from anywhere? (0.0.0.0/0)

Answer (score 2):

From: http://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity

edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf and replace this line:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

with

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

and restart the mysqld server.

Answer (score 1):

I had a big problem with external conection in EC2 too, I could only connect after I created a new user with all grant options, I seems like root access can only connect on localhost.

I did evething I could, oppened my firewall, changed my.conf directives and it only worked when I created another user with all grants.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. external db might be firewalled or your mysql on external server only accept connections from that host.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a security group (in AWS) set up for the box?

If so, have you allowed the port you've specified?

Comment: yes, i have a security group set up. Traffic is allowed on port 22,80 and 3306. Is there another setting for outgoing traffic.